# Deploying a C#/.NET application without an installer nor ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, installation

I am looking for a solution to:

1. I don't have authorisation for installing an application on a client computer. That's why I need to deploy the application without an installer. Just like a portable application or a standalone application - something like that.
2. The client computer also has a limitation in its Internet connection, so ClickOnce will not work either.
3. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010. I saw [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) could solve my limitation in setting-up my application. But still, I can't install the application.

Comment: Just 'deploy' your `Bin` folder, make sure all assemblies are set to `CopyLocal = True` and unless you're doing something specific that's all you need. It's the same way that the code runs from VS when you press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run.

Comment: there are some assemblies won't set to true;microsoft.office.core,microsoft.office.interop,VBIDE, how do i change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your solution, set [CopyLocal to true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for all projects. This will ensure that the `..\Bin` folder contains all the necessary assemblies for your program. Then just zip up the `..\Bin` folder, get it onto the client machine, and then unzip it.

Comment: It's worth noting that some of the files in that folder are likely to be debugging files that won't be needed by end users.

Comment: if there are some assemblies can't set to true is that would be a problem?i made application for automating excel but the office & interop assemblies wont set to true?how to fix it?

Comment: Found this answer and it worked for me, but I had to look up how to set the CopyLocal setting.  Here is the result I found, for future reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx